# Construct Dropdown in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a list of Car Manufacturers stored in my Database. This is part of my main layout of my site so in my layout.cshtml. I have a CarManufacturers controller that returns the data from the DB where the list of Car Manufacturers are stored.

I then have a CarManufacturers view model like below:

```
public class CarManufacturersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CarManufacturersList { get; set; }

    public int SelectedCarManufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

The method to Get Car manufacturers from the Db and return the Partial view is below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var carManufacturers = _dbService.GetAll<CarManufacturer>();

        var model = new CarManufacturersViewModel
        {
            CarManufacturersList = carManufacturers.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                Text = c.Name
            })
        };

        return PartialView("_CarManufacturersDropDown", model);
    }
```

When you select a car manufacturer from the drop down list in the cshtml view another action on the controller is hit - which is below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CarManufacturersViewModelwModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController", new { carManufacturerId = model.SelectedCarManufacturer });
    }
```

My view then in the partial is as below:

```
@model MyProj.Models.CarManufacturersViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#carmanufacturers').change(function () {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });

    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CarManufacturers", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCarManufacturer, Model.CarManufacturersList, "Car Manufacturer Details", new { id = "carmanufacturers" })
}
```

This works but I want to not use a @Html.DropDownListFor and just build my own bootstrap Dropdown list - some like [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) so the markup is:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this with MVC - so I still retrieve the data for the dropdown list from the database and then each item in the dropdown list will pass its own id to the Post method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

First:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="manuDropWrap">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    @foreach (var manu in Model.CarManufacturersList)
    {
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitemm" href="#" data-id="@manu.Value">@manu.Text</a></li>
    }
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" value="@Model.SelectedCarManufacturer" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.SelectedCarManufacturer)" id="selectedManu" />
</div>

<script type="text/html">
  $("#manuDropWrap > li").each(function () {
                $(this).click(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                    $("#selectedManu").val(id);
                    $(this).closest('form').submit();
                });
            });
</script>
```

Second:

You can prepare own `HtmlHelper` extensions that generates proper html.

Remarks: written from memory, small mistakes can happen.

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat since you have accepted - I hope it wokrs :)